# GB18030 vs Big5 Chinese character encodings sizewise

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

We've two encodings available for Chinese characters, **GB18030** and **Big5** for Chinese Simplified and Chinese Traditional respectively.

How many byte(s)/octet(s) a single Chinese character would take in each encoding?

Comment: Why the down vote? Thanks for asking this question. I've up vote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by Wikipedia:

[GB_18030 - Guójiā Biāozhǔn (国家标准)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030#Technical_details) is a 4 octets(bytes) encoding scheme. Hence, every character should take 4 octets. Same is said on [GB18030 - New Chinese Encoding Standard](http://www.gb18030.com/)

[Big-5 or Big5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5#Organization) is a 2 octets(bytes) encoding scheme. Here every character takes 2 octets.